# Designing binary search tree class inheriting from binary tree class

Tags: c#, oop, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am creating a binary search tree class in c#. I am creating the class by deriving from a binary tree class because binary search tree is a kind of binary tree. So i will have most of the common methods inside binary tree class and share them inside binary search tree.

Now:
    BinaryTree class has two methods "AddToLeft" and "AddToRight" methods, these two methods must able able to access outside this class, i.e in Main method to add nodes to the binary tree. so i made them public. and these two methods should also be accessible inside binary search tree class ( reusing) to add node to the binarysearchtree based on condition.

But now since Insert method is the candidate for the binarysearchtree to insert nodes to BST but AddToLeft and AddToRight are not. so these two methods should not be exposed to the clients(outside world) of my binarysearch tree on the BST object. How to design this class.?

I tried:

1. making those two methods sealed in the binarytree class, it did not help.
2. declared them public in base and protected in derived. that too did not help as public can't be inherited as protected in derived class.

Please help to design the classes.

```
public class BTNode
{
    public int data;
    public BTNode Left { get; set; }
    public BTNode Right { get; set; }
    public BTNode(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public class BinaryTree
{
    public BTNode Root { get; set;}
    public BinaryTree() : this(null) { }
    public BinaryTree(BTNode node) { Root = node; }
    // this method common for its derived class too
    public void AddToLeft(BTNode current, BTNode node) 
    {
        current.Left = node;
    }

    // this method common for its derived class too
    public void AddToRight(BTNode current, BTNode node)
    {
        current.Right = node;
    }
}

public class BinarySearchTree : BinaryTree
{       
    public BinarySearchTree(int val)
    {
        Root = new BTNode(val);    
    }
    public void Insert(int val)
    {
        BTNode node = new BTNode(val);

        if (Root.data >= val)
            base.AddToLeft(Root, node); // I should be able to call this method here
        else
            base.AddToRight(Root, node); // I should be able to call this method here
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BinaryTree bt = new BinaryTree();
        BTNode root = new BTNode(3);
        BTNode node1 = new BTNode(4);
        BTNode node2 = new BTNode(7);

        bt.AddToLeft(root,node1); // i should be able to access this method here.
        bt.AddToLeft(root, node2); // i should be able to access this method here.

        BinarySearchTree bst = new BinarySearchTree(6);
        bst.Insert(4);
        bst.Insert(8);

        // This is the problem.
        // these two methods should not be visible on the bst object.
        // insertion to bst is done only through insert() method
        // but these two methods should be accessible inside the binarysearchtree class
        // to add the nodes.
        bst.AddToLeft(root,node1); // i should not access this method here on this object
        bst.AddToRight(root, node2); // i should not access this method here on this object
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do as you typed your code is a contradiction. You are saying your class is a type of `BinaryTree`, but you don't want to honor the contract that would make it a `BinaryTree`.

What I would probably do is not derive from `BinaryTree` and instead have a private field that holds a `BinaryTree` in your `BinarySearchTree` class and expose the functionality you want to expose through public accessors in `BinaryTree` (So `BinarySearchTree` is no longer a type of Binary Tree, but still has access to the functionality through a private field initialized with an instance of a `BinaryTree`.)

I can certainly understand the appeal of making `BinarySearchTree` a type of `BinaryTree`, but you either give up the encapsulation of those two methods or the classification of the base type. You can't claim to meet the requirements of classification of the base type when you aren't offering the same external API as it is.

If you really wanted to be able to try to do things like you did above, you could override the methods you don't want clients using and throw `InvalidOperationException`s from those methods. But this isn't very elegant as it doesn't help you at compile time, and will only complain at run time which is not prudent design.

Comment: Yes, your comment make sense that when BinarySearchTree is a type of BinaryTree, it has to comply with the contract given by BinaryTree. So i am going to favour composition than inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

try using private keyword of both of the AddToLeft and AddToRight methods instead of public. since private methods are only visible to base class.

Thanks

Comment: No, i want those two methods to be accessed even outside BinaryTree class, thats in my Main method as given in my example

Answer (score 0):

More on the contradiction -- it's a metaphysics issue: A BinarySearchTree is not a BinaryTree, if the definition of a BinaryTree is that it must be able to perform left and right adds.  As you know, a BinaryTree is a *structure* that has two child nodes of each node. A BinarySearchTree is not a BinaryTree, but rather is a key-based sorted list that *uses* a BinaryTree for internal storage.

The first is a structure, the second is a higher level structure with a specific internal storage structure and algorithm to go with it.  BinarySearchTree is probably best subclassed from Dictionary, where KeyType is the index type and ValueType is the type stored at each node (which could be a set).  You want to be able to add elements with a key to the collection, and pull them back later by that key, with some additional benefits (sorted traversal perhaps, etc.).  That's a dictionary extension, not a BinaryTree extension, so your approach to wrap it up is the way to go, and I would implement IDictionary.